# What is correct way to create a NSSlider with two thumbs(knobs)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, custom-controls, nsslider

I need to specify a range let's say the

minvalue is 0
maxvalue is 100

thumb1 value can range from minvalue to thumb1 value
thumb2 value can range from thumb1 value to maxvalue

Basically they should not overlap.

Is there any other solution other than control available with out creating custom NSSlider

Thanks for the help

Comment: From your descriptions it looks like you need two slider, not a custom slider

Comment: Nope. One Slider with two thumbs - http://www.componentone.com/newimages/products/screenshots/studioxaml/RangeSlider/rangeslider.png